# Is there a method to quantify the return time to equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'd like to know how fast (or slow) a dynamical system will return to equilibrium, especially if it is near an unstable equilibrium.

The question is vague, but that is intentional.  I'm looking for any reading material that could help me in this respect.

Comment: When you say "equilibrium", do you mean "statistical equilibrium" as in a large system of interacting particles? Or are you referring to the stable and unstable fixed points of a dynamical system?

Comment: @JohnBarber Dynamical system

Comment: Generally, the amount of time required for a dynamical system to "arrive" *at* a stable fixed point is infinite, since the rate of approach drops to zero as the system draws nearer and nearer to the fixed point. Do you mean: "How long does it take for a dynamical system to go from the *vicinity* of an unstable fixed point to the *vicinity* of a stable fixed point?" If so, then the time will be dominated by the parts of the trajectory *near* the two fixed points. The time spent in those regions can indeed be estimated via linearization, as noted below.

Comment: A very good, basic reference would be Strogatz's book *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos*.

Comment: I think that your question needs further clarification. I presume that you are speaking about smooth flows. Then you should understand that 1) there is no such thing as "returning exactly to the equilibrium" -- it always takes infinite amount of time to arrive at it; 2) there is such thing as "returning to the neighbourhood of the equilibrium", but you need some global structure that allows trajectories return to it. It can be a homoclinic loop as in case of saddle-focus or chain of connections as in heteroclinic network between saddle equilibria.

Comment: I can't say if these are all possible mechanisms, but some sort of recurrence is surely needed here. Speaking about the return time, consider the simplest case of a homoclinic loop. If you fix the neighbourhood of your saddle equilbrium, then the time of return tends to the time that point spends travelling on one-dimensional unstable manifold outside of your chosen neighbourhood. Quite similar 'asymptotics' holds in case of heteroclinic network between saddle equilibria.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform something called linear stability analysis that if the forcing function is linear. This same method can be applied to non linear systems.

The first few chapters of this book deal with what I think is what you want.
http://bookstore.siam.org/cl21/

Comment: But the question started near an unstable equilibrium so that approximation will likely fail quickly.